# REST API that allows CRUD based operations on its objects

Tags: api, rest, powerbi, crud

I have one api and I need to access the data in power bi. From where I can start.

Details as per below

To fetch a task with ID 123, you would perform the following
curl -g -X GET -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: bearer YourTokenHere' 'https://app.celoxis.com/psa/api/v2/tasks/123'

Thanks
Imran